# How to re-order records after insert of a new record, VBA, MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, vba

I currently have a form which displays records in descending order of an incremented number per record. Although after I insert a new record the records order is like so:

```
4, 3, 2, 1, 5
```

But I need it to look like this after insert:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

I have the follow code which onLoad sorts the problem, but I want to order the records after a new record is input.

```
Me.OrderBy = "Table1.Field1 DESC"
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can requery:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: My problem was that I had other code in the AfterInsert event, this caused problems, I moved the code into BeforeInsert and just had me.requery and BOOM!